# How to pass the current item of ngFor-loop to event's callback?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

There is the ngFor loop in the component's template:

```
@Component({
  template:'
    <div *ngIf="List">
      <div *ngFor="let item of List" (click)="onSelect(item)">
      ...
     </div>
   </div> '
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
  List: MyCustomItem[];
  ngOnInit() {
    //load List from server
  }

  onSelect(item: MyCustomItem) {...}
}
```

So I want to call onSelect callback when user click on the element and pass needed MyCustomItem instance to it as argument. However this code not working (onSelect get undefined). How can I do it?

Comment: Please post more code. What does `List` look like?. This usually just works.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, I have updated my question

Comment: Should work . . .. . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this code should work, but only if you're correctly getting the List data from your server.

"***onSelect get undefined***":

This means that your List is empty. Make sure you are getting the data from your List service.

As suggested in the comments post the piece of code inside your ngOnInit() function so we could troubleshoot this. And if you are using a service, post the piece of code in your service, responsible for retrieving the List.

Comment: You was almost right. I loaded items for List correctly however my typescript properties of  MyCustomItem was invalid (i.e. not same as server-side model), so onSelect was not able to bind properties from server-model to MyCustomItem instance for argument.

Comment: Oh, sorry! Maybe "correctly getting the List data from your server" was too broad, I should have been more explicit. Glad it's working now!